# TFS Gated build progress indicator is not working correctly

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfsbuild

I used to use VS 2010 with TFS 2010 and everything was fine. Since I upgraded to VS 2012 and at the same time TFS 2012 build progress indicator is not working correct. It shows Started 0 seconds ago and it will stay until end of the build, then says build is done. I tried using VS 2013 Preview and nothing different.

[image]

Is this TFS 2012 problem or Visual Studio? How can that be solved?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you recreate this on a different developer's workstation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just upgraded to Windows 8.1 and now it is working fine. Maybe I shouldn't say upgrading to Windows 8.1 will fix it. Because I have another machine that has Windows 8.1 Preview and I can still reproduce it. Upgrading from Windows fixed it. Thanks everyone for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in this registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\TeamFoundation\Build\UISettings
```

for a ReportPollingInterval node.  If it's there then delete it (if it's not then this probably doesn't answer your question).

Comment: I had that Registry key and deleted it. Nothing changed.

Comment: I assume you restarted VS?

Comment: The default (if the key doesn't exist) should be 10 seconds... you could try setting the key to 10 and see if that helps... but I doubt it will as that should be the default.

Comment: I deleted the Key and it had two values in there. They all gone. I thought VS will recreate them. So any way. I think I know what you are you trying to explain. My Visual Studio refreshes the Build report page every 10 seconds or sometimes I press F5 to see what is happening. It even shows the log in there while it is running. Only the problem is time. It doesn't show how long ago build started until the end of build.